# problem with using flutter twitter_login package

Tags: authentication, flutter, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to use this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_twitter_login 
to allow the user to login to my flutter app with their twitter accounts 
I only did the steps in the package's page but every time I try to call the login method 
I get this output:

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001110c48db __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110667ac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001110c4735 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   TwitterKit                          0x00000001103b38ad -[TWTRTwitter logInWithViewController:completion:] + 649
    4   Runner                              0x000000010a3527dd -[TwitterLoginPlugin authorize:] + 205
    5   Runner                              0x000000010a3522cf -[TwitterLoginPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] + 335
    6   Flutter                             0x000000010c9584fd __45-[FlutterMethodChannel setMethodCallHandler:]<…>
Lost connection to device.
```

here is my code

```
final TwitterLogin twitterLogin = new TwitterLogin(
    consumerKey: 'kkOvaF1Mowy4JTvCxKTV5O1WF',
    consumerSecret: 'ZECGsI6UUDBEUVGkJe4S5vd0FGqGxC3wMJCgsXgPRfjSwRFnyH',
  );
  String _message = 'Logged out.';
  void _loginTwitter() async {
    final TwitterLoginResult result = await twitterLogin.authorize();
    String newMessage;

    switch (result.status) {
      case TwitterLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        newMessage = 'Logged in! username: ${result.session.username}';
        break;
      case TwitterLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        newMessage = 'Login cancelled by user.';
        break;
      case TwitterLoginStatus.error:
        newMessage = 'Login error: ${result.errorMessage}';
        break;
    }

    setState(() {
      _message = newMessage;
    });
  }
```

this is the line that's throw the error
 `final TwitterLoginResult result = await twitterLogin.authorize();`

Comment: Please could you post the code that is throwing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Just try the code :

```
static final TwitterLogin twitterLogin = TwitterLogin(
    consumerKey: 'kkOvaF1Mowy4JTvCxKTV5O1WF',
    consumerSecret: 'ZECGsI6UUDBEUVGkJe4S5vd0FGqGxC3wMJCgsXgPRfjSwRFnyH',
  );

  Future<bool> _loginTwitter() async {
    var twitterLoginResult = await twitterLogin.authorize();

    switch (twitterLoginResult.status) {
      case TwitterLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        print("Status : ${twitterLoginResult.session.toMap()}");
        break;
      case TwitterLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        print("Cancell");
        break;
      case TwitterLoginStatus.error:
        print("Error");
        break;
    }

    return twitterLogin.isSessionActive;
  }
```

just make a call on your tap method.

```
onPressed:() async{
bool b = await _loginTwitterUserWithoutFirebase();
}
```

This is perfectly working fine.

Comment: I have tried your keyand it is working fine in my code. Try the updated code in my answer with replacing your code.

Comment: no still will shut down the app . can you share your delegate.swift and info.plist files